# Failed to darken a background-image using css multiples backgrounds

Tags: css

I tried to add multiples backgrounds on top of each other to a div (a semi-transparent background on top of an image). I did it in this way :

```
background-image: url(imgurl), rgb(0 0 0 / 85%);
```

I got a message "invalid property value"

the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_backgrounds_and_borders/Using_multiple_backgrounds) it says :

> You can apply multiple backgrounds to elements. These are layered atop
> one another with the first background you provide on top and the last
> background listed in the back. Only the last background can include a
> background color.

All I need is just to darken the background-image with that semi-transparent background on top of it.
How to achieve it ?

BTW, I can't apply filter on the dom element as it has another content that should remain visible and I can't use multiples layers (dom elements) on top of each other.

Comment: a color is not an image, a gradient is an image